# THYMELEAF error - Error resolving template

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I see this question with hundreds of answers, none of which have worked for me yet.  I am building a simple asset tracker.  My controller has two functions

```
@Controller
public class GpsController {

    private double bestLat = 0.0;
    private double bestLon = 0.0;
    private double divisor = 10000000.0;

    @GetMapping("/map")
    public String map(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("latitude", bestLat);
        model.addAttribute("longitude", bestLon);
        return "map";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addlocation")
    public void addLocation(@RequestBody GpsMessage message) {
        if(message.getGpsTimestamp() == 0L) {
            bestLat = message.getTriLat();
            bestLon = message.getTriLon();
        } else {
            bestLat = message.getGpsLat() / divisor;
            bestLon = message.getGpsLon() / divisor;
        }
        DbConnection.writeLocation(message);
    }
}
```

I'm using Thymeleaf in /map to pass the latitude and longitude into the JS for the Google Maps API.  The program works just fine, but I get these errors from Thymeleaf.  I could ignore it but I prefer to find what is causing it.

2022-06-13 05:18:14.177 ERROR 28188 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "***addlocation***": Error resolving template [***addlocation***], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [***addlocation***], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]

at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]*

What confuses me is that it is complaining about the *addLocation* method when it is not using  thymeleaf.

In resources, I have index.html, index.js, and style.css inside the static folder and the map.html file under templates.

map.html looks like this if it matters...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Add Map</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        var myLat = /*[[${latitude}]]*/;
        var myLon = /*[[${longitude}]]*/;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--The div element for the map -->
<div id="map"></div>
<script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
        defer
></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message is not complaining about the Java `addLocation` method (with an uppercase `L`). It is complaining about a non-existent or misplaced Thymeleaf `addlocation` template. Note the lowercase `l` in `addlocation`. Look in your code for references to `addlocation` (all lowercase). The complete stack trace (not provided in the question) should tell you exactly where in your code you need to look.